# "Interpolate previous value" of the same table in SQL

Tags: sql, join, interpolation, vertica

I faced with a problem where I need to do something that works as interpolate previous value in join, but not from the table I join but from the original one. Let me explain:

```
Table A:

Item Package Start_date Finish_date
 X   12345   2020-01-01 2020-02-01
 X   6789    2020-02-02 2020-03-02


Table B

Item   Date     
 X   2020-01-15 
 X   2020-02-15
 X   2020-03-15
```

I want to know, in which package from table A was my Item at date from Table B. So I do:

```
select Item, Date, Package 
from B
left join A on (B.Item = A.Item and B.Date between StartDate and FinishDate)
```

and I get:

```
Item  Date      Package
X   2020-01-15  12345
X   2020-02-15  6789
X   2020-03-15  NULL
```

but instead of null I'd like to see the last non-empty value of Package, event if the date is out of date range (here it will be 6789).

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: By the way, what you are doing is *extrapolation* not *interpolation*.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can comfortably use a left join with `INTERPOLATE PREVIOUS VALUE` here, there might be data constellations where you need the exact complex join predicate, with an equi and a BETWEEN predicate combined, that you are using.

If you need that (I can't come up with cases where you would off the top of my head, so help me there) it would be a simple OLAP, Window, function that is available in Vertica: `LAST_VALUE(<_expression_> IGNORE NULLS)`, which returns the last non-null value in the OLAP window.

But I doubt you need it, so I add both solutions here below.

Repeating your input in an initial `WITH` clause involving two Common Table Expressions, with your join, it should look like this:

```
WITH
a(item,package,start_date,finish_date) as (
          SELECT 'X',12345,DATE '2020-01-01',DATE '2020-02-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 'X',6789,DATE '2020-02-02',DATE '2020-03-02'
)
,
b(item,date) AS (
          SELECT 'X',DATE '2020-01-15'
UNION ALL SELECT 'X',DATE '2020-02-15'
UNION ALL SELECT 'X',DATE '2020-03-15'
)
SELECT
  b.item
, b.date
, LAST_VALUE(a.package IGNORE NULLS) OVER(w) AS package
FROM b
LEFT JOIN a 
 ON a.item=b.item
AND b.date BETWEEN start_date AND finish_date
WINDOW w AS(PARTITION BY b.item ORDER BY b.date)
ORDER BY 2;
-- out  item |    date    | package 
-- out ------+------------+---------
-- out  X    | 2020-01-15 |   12345
-- out  X    | 2020-02-15 |    6789
-- out  X    | 2020-03-15 |    6789
```

The `INTERPOLATE PREVIOUS VALUE` left join predicate works, though, also in this data constellation, as you can see here below.

```
WITH
a(item,package,start_date,finish_date) as (
          SELECT 'X',12345,DATE '2020-01-01',DATE '2020-02-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 'X',6789,DATE '2020-02-02',DATE '2020-03-02'
)
,
b(item,date) AS (
          SELECT 'X',DATE '2020-01-15'
UNION ALL SELECT 'X',DATE '2020-02-15'
UNION ALL SELECT 'X',DATE '2020-03-15'
)
SELECT
  b.item
, b.date
, a.package
FROM b
LEFT JOIN a 
 ON a.item=b.item
AND b.date INTERPOLATE PREVIOUS VALUE start_date
ORDER BY 2;
-- out  item |    date    | package 
-- out ------+------------+---------
-- out  X    | 2020-01-15 |   12345
-- out  X    | 2020-02-15 |    6789
-- out  X    | 2020-03-15 |    6789
```

Worth trying which is quicker - the range join predicate or the INTERPOLATE PREVIOUS VALUE predicate.

Worth checking which version is quicker - and you're not always in the comfortable position of having a `finish_date` to play with ...

Can you try both, and tell us which one was quicker?

Answer (score 0):

Use two `join`s.  One for the match and one for the default:

```
select b.Item, b.Date, 
       coalesce(a.Package, adef.Package) as Package 
from B left join
     A
     on B.Item = A.Item and
        B.Date between A.StartDate and A.FinishDate left join
     (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item order by StartDate desc) as seqnum
      from a
     ) adef
     on adef.item = B.item and
        adef.seqnum = 1 and
        a.item is null;
```

EDIT:

You could actually combine this into one `join`:

```
select b.Item, b.Date, a.Package
from B left join
     (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item order by StartDate desc) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a
     on adef.item = B.item and
        B.Date >= A.StartDate and
        (B.Date <= A.FinishDate or
         (B.Date > A.FinishDate and seqnum = 1)
        );
```

Comment: could you please explain why there is "seqnum - 1" in the (B.Date > A.FinishDate and seqnum - 1)? what would change without it?

Comment: How will it change, if there id just one date in B for item X, and its out of all the Dates interval from A? but I still need to get the last Package

Comment: (1) The `-` was a typo.  (2) That is what these queries do.